# Use a lambda function to find the maximum of a list in python

Tags: python, lambda

I am new to python and trying to learn.

Say i have a list: lst = [22, 36, 47, 2, 13]

I know I can use max(lst) to get the max element but I want to know how to do this using a lamda function.

Can anyone show me?

Comment: Please show your own effort. Add code what you have done this far and point where is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your lambda using **[reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)**:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> 
>>> lst = [22, 36, 47, 2, 13]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x if (x > y) else y, lst)
47
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lambda_max = lambda x: max(x)
lambda_max(list)
```